# Не запускается операционная система

Tags: linux, железо

Мои действия по порядку:

1. Отформатировал диск С на винде
2. разобрал почистил собрал ноутбук
3. установил с флешки дистрибутив линукса(zorin os),при установке были видны все существующие разделы и колличество занимаемой и свободной памяти, следовательно жёсткий диск не поврежден физически
4. перезагружаюсь и мне вылетает ошибка:

   ```
   Boot device not found
   Please install an operation system on your hard disk.
   Hard disk -(3FO)
   ```

Искал решение в интернете,везде пишут одно и тоже:

- сбросить настройки Биоса
- сделать полную перезагрузку
- поставить:

  - legasy boot - enable
  - security boot- disable

Всё это пытался делать и результата не дало

Ноутбук `hp proBook 455 g2`

Меню Биоса кстати не как обычно в "ретро стиле" а в формате от hp, и некоторые пункты там называются по-другому, возможно проблема в том что я неправильно все-таки проделал действия с таким интерфейсом, было бы неплохо если бы смогли описать алгоритм для такого биоса.

ОБНОВЛЕНО:
принял во внимание советы,скачал убунту на флешку, загрузился с неё и отформатировал все разделы кроме двух (это бывшие диск Е и D от винды) разбил диск на swap , root и выделил несколько мегабайт на "резервная загрузочная область биос" , устройством для установки системного загрузчика поставил сам диск. В итоге, установка завершилась все ок, для входа в систему просит перезагрузиться, перезагружаю и проблема собственно та же что и в начале. Ставил в boot options  legasy и в самый верх ставил notebook hard drive проблема осталась. Поставил уэфи, а в порядке загрузки нет самого жёсткого диска. Его можно выбрать в boot device options но проблема остаётся

ОБНОВЛЕНО 2:
Видимо проблема в том что диск размечен не в том формате что нужно для установки убунты, и без удаления всех данных этого не решить, я пять форматнул кусок диска и поставил винду.
Возможно уже рядом с ней можно будет поставить Линукс ,но я уже оставлю так

Comment: Видимо при установке ОС не был установлен загрузчик на HDD или он был повреждён.

Comment: Если этот Zorin OS умеет работать с флешки, то загрузись с нее и посмотри имеющиеся разделы. Если они есть, можешь воспользоваться любой статьей: Восстановление загрузчика `grub` в Ubuntu.

Comment: И, судя по вопросу, я не советую тебе "для начала" ставить "неведомый" дистрибутив, собираемый непонятно кем и как, ради "модных" иконок и веселой картинки на рабочем столе. Ставь что-нибудь популярное: *Ubuntu, Debian, Mint, Centos... Надежность выше и ответ на вопросы проще найти. Не 97 год, когда ставилось то, что в прокате дисков было...

Comment: судя по этим вашим интернетам в этом вашем ноутбуке стоит не bios, а uefi. что подразумевает наличие выделенного раздела на блочном устройстве. с файловой системой fat на нём, в которую и записываются файлы с загрузчиками операционной системы. вы этот раздел не снесли, случайно? а загрузчик в него записали? (об этом спрашивает инсталлятор, обычно где-нибудь в конце процесса установки)

Comment: Обычно когда устанавливаешь дистрибутив через графический установщик, там можно открыть раздел разметки диска, и там предлагается выбрать, куда устанавливать загрузчик. Выбирать для загрузчика нужно именно диск целиком, а не какой-то из его разделов.

Answer (score 1):

Сообщение, которое Вы приводите, говорит о том, что на диске, на котором расположен раздел который отмечен в таблице разделов как "Загрузочный" отсутствует начальный загрузчик.

Во время установки ОС, инсталлятор должен был спросить Вас, на какой диск (!), а не раздел пишем IPL. Вспомните, что Вы ответили на этот вопрос.

А теперь смотрим BIOS - порядок устройств загрузки. Посмотрите, в этом списке есть устройство, на которое инсталлятор записал IPL ?

Comment: не всегда срабатывает. точнее срабатывает только на съёмных носителях. тут нужны танцы с 2мя загрузочными разделами.

Answer (score 1):

Если диск размечен в GPT, то насильно стартует загрузчик UEFI на некоторых BIOS. В не особо поддерживаемых дистрибутивах часто это не принимают во внимание и ставят загрузчик grub без поддержки efi. Он может конечно запуститься, но если на диске есть разделы `04 BIOS boot` и `01 EFI System`. Или нужно поставить grub-efi загрузчик с предзагручиком в разделе `01 EFI System`. Потом Secure Boot - можно включить если установить подписанный предзагрузчик.

Проще "форматнуть" всё в MBR - там будет сразу работать только Legacy Boot.

Есть ещё вариант использовать виндовый или "стандартный" загрузчик для запуска linux, но на практике не видел.